# Do we allow image answers?

Tags: support, answers, allowed-answers

Flagged [an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270873/) for only providing an image, akin to link-only answers, and had it declined because "I should not flag answers for inaccuracy".

The entire answer is an image, which as far as I was aware, posed the same problem as hyperlinks.

It would have taken a lot more effort to read my post on inaccuracies, and you would quite literally have to be blind to miss the fact that there is only an image in the answer, with a reference link to Reddit. I assume my original interpretation of not allowing image-only answers was incorrect.

Do we allow image-only answers?

Comment: We've always allowed image only answers. The difference is that SE hosts the picture.

Comment: @Frank,SE owns imgur?

Comment: No. But they have a deal with them for dedicated hosting, I believe.

Comment: http://stack.imgur.com/

Comment: It's not on stack Imgur now, but any 2k can edit it to upload it to stack Imgur.

Comment: @Unionhawk done.

Comment: @Frank, would you mind posting as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Images are not like videos or links. Videos and links can/do suffer from link-rot. Images, however can, and should, be hosted on SE's imgur host. So images will not suffer from the same sort of rot.

That said, **image only posts should be judged by the same merits as any other posts**. If an image is explanatory and gives all the relevant information, great. In fact, we have lots of image only or image driven answers that get right to the point. If someone asks where something is, sometimes a map or screenshot is enough to get the relevant information. It is probably not the best answer, but that doesn't make it an awful answer either.

The major caveat for me with images is accessibility. You need to make sure that the descriptive text is helpful in explaining the content of the image. It should allow someone who can't see the image, for one reason or another, to understand the contents and still get the answer to the question.

Now, about the flag in this case. Flags should be used when content is so low quality it can't be fixed or improved. A flag here seems more like a super downvote than trying to denote something that needs moderator attention. Remember, when you flag something, make sure it's something you think needs/warrants moderator attention. I know our mods are happy to help, but also have a lot of things to do as well as lives outside here. So just be mindful of that. *A flag, like a close vote, is not a super downvote.*

Long and short of it: Judge image-only answers by the same bar you would judge other posts. With the minor caveat that making sure it is accessible is extra important in this case.

Comment: Just on the accessibility front, if you are giving a primarily-image-based answer, at least be sure to [give it a proper description](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7470/28182). That text where it says 'Enter Image description here' is read out loud by screen readers as the image description (as well as being presented as text when the image can't load, which happens occasionally)

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad answer. Downvote it, and vote to delete if rep allows.

It's not a non-answer. It ought not be flagged. *Particularly* not with the generic NAA flag. As Moderators, we can't always be counted on to evaluate NAA flags beyond "does this look sort of relevant?". We can't be counted on to understand the difference between a wrong answer, and one that misunderstands the question completely, when the distinction requires some amount of game knowledge. Use the generic NAA flag for Me Too, Thanks, nonsense, or follow up questions.

If the reason an answer is a non-answer requires some amount of understanding, use the custom field and explain it to us.

Regardless of all that, the fact that the answer is primarily an image is not a problem. I'd generally downvote it unless the information truly couldn't be presented any other way, because it's a poor accessibility practice, but in and of itself, it is not a problem that warrants deletion or flags.

Comment: Ironically, this doesnt even attempt to answer the question being asked.

Comment: @Timelord64 in general, if it requires some understanding of the subject to make that judgment, raise a custom flag and explain that fact. Use the generic NAA flag for Me Too, Thanks, nonsense, or follow up questions. As moderators, we can't always be counted on to evaluate NAA flags beyond "this looks sort of relevant but I have no idea if it's correct". Which is why we decline those flags. Because if it's wrong, that's what a downvote is for.

Comment: which is all good and well **but that doesnt answer the question**. I know that you dont flag a question for being wrong. ***I did not flag the question for being wrong***. You literally have to ignore the first comment, and still read the second, to come to that conclussion.

Comment: Honestly, with the greatest of respect, I feel you make a poor argument that you can be counted on to better understand a custom flag, given that you insist on ignoring, or are still utterly oblivious to the fact that I am asking about whether we accept image-only questions =/

Comment: @Timelord64 I'm only addressing the wrongness of it because you brought it up in response to me here. It's a bad answer because it's an image with no context. Bad answers get downvotes. They don't get flags.

Comment: unless, ofcourse, we did not accept image only answers. Which is what I am asking about =/ I dont think there is a further point trying to discuss this.. other users have understood the question quite clearly, and answered the question.

Comment: @Timelord64 I understood the question quite clearly. An image only answer is often a *bad* answer. It is not *not* an answer. We accept bad answers and we downvote them. If anyone is having trouble reading what the other one is saying, it's you.

Comment: You havnt once addressed why we accept image-only answers, when in theory the have the same issue as link-only answers.

Comment: My comment on the answer, itself, clearly states my original understanding that we dont allow image only answers for the reasons we dont allow link-only answers.

Comment: @Timelord64 I've repeatedly posted that I think concerns about link based answers are dramatically overblown as well. As with images, I feel they are often bad answers, but rarely not answers.

Comment: thats all good and great, but Im asking about site policy, not your opinion. Regardless, another user has provided support on why images are more acceptable than links, and I am happy with the answer. Ultimately, I am asking for *support* not *discussion*. Now I know not to flag image only questions, not because a mod doesnt like it,but because they are not a real problem as I had misinterpreted.